# Java - How to deserialize a CSV file to JavaBeans

Tags: java

I want to parse a java object to XML String form CSV file.

for example, I got csv like this with all the column is optional:

```
name,age,class,level
jon,12,archer,12
```

then I want to parse it to XML with the output like (for example I don't need the level column):

```
<char>
     <name>jon</name>
     <age>12</name>
     <class>archer</class>
</char>
```

for the Object to XML, it is easy since I just need to use @XmlElement to parse.
But it was quite confusing for me to parse CSV to Object to do the remaining thing.
I've tried using Jsefa but it just can return an Object not a bean for me to add the annotation

Comment: Is xml or csv a hard requirement? A binary format like Protobuf would be more efficient and preserve type information

Comment: Then why not read the csv and convert it to java object... and then do what you do with java object... you can use jackson if you wish. 

Or you can go alternate way... 1st try to convert csv to json, and then json to xml.

try this link: http://atozjavatutorials.blogspot.com/2015/06/read-data-from-csv-file-and-map-it-to.html

Comment: yeah since CSV and XML are both hard requirement. If I convert CSV to JSON and then JSON to XML then it is kind of time-consuming since I could just parse the CSV to map and parse it to a bean and generate XML on that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenCSV to read CSV and convert to Java object. You can refer its documentation and examples at [OpenCSV Reading into beans](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_beans)

Information about how to add OpenCSV to your project is avaialble at [Addng OpenCSV to your project](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html)

Comment: So could this make the column in CSV optional, since sometime I don't need all the CSV column value to appear in my XML

Comment: I think even optional columns should work. You can quickly try it out. I have updated the answer with link to how to add OpenCSV to your project.