# Import CSV file to MySQL database using JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a csv file of different attributes i.e columns, example: name, rollno, department. I want to store it to a MySQL database which contains a table and the same attributes as the csv file. I want to import it to the database using JSP.

Comment: I don't know your exact use case nor the feasibility but wouldn't it make much more sense to read the csv from jsp -> send to java backend (servlets, sprint,etc) -> read csv and save to database?

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169360/1776132 for details to use OpenCSV to read csv files in java.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).