# How to Store and Get the individual values in the Below Response..?

Tags: java, list, selenium, dictionary, automation

[image]

**responseGetCsv** is giving below response as in the picture,

<200 OK,Device CustomIPv6 Address 4,Version,Request URL Query,Device CustomIPv6 Address 1,Destination Identity Phone Home,Device Action,Crypto Signature,Old File Size,Flex Date 1 Label,Category Significance,Old File Hash
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,
,1,,,,,,,,/Informational,,{Server=[nginx/1.12.2], Date=[Mon, 09 Dec 2019 09:14:03 GMT], Content-Type=[application/octet-stream], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], X-Powered-By=[Sails ], Cache-Control=[private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Expires=[-1], Pragma=[no-cache], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[], Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=[], Access-Control-Allow-Methods=[], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[], Access-Control-Expose-Headers=[], Content-Disposition=[attachment; filename="testGetCsv_09/12/2019 14:43:43.csv";], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains;]}>

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169200/java-how-to-deserialize-a-csv-file-to-javabeans/59169360#59169360

Comment: just parse it line by line with splitter for ',' sign

Comment: @Vault23 Can u plz explain briefly how to do, If possible give one small example